# hibernate one to many list mapping error

Tags: xml, hibernate, mapping

I have the following hibernate xml mapping file segment.

```
   

    <list name="networks" cascade="all">
                <key column="parent_id"/>    

                <one-to-many class="Network"/>
        </list>
```

it produced the following exception, why?   it does have the mentioned elements.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "list" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,key,(index|list-index),(element|one-to-many|many-to-many|composite-element|many-to-any),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,sql-delete-all?,filter*)".
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuratio
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `<list-index` is mandatory for `<List >` mapping.

```
<list name="networks" cascade="all">
    <key column="parent_id"/>    
    <list-index column="order" base="0" />
    <one-to-many class="Network"/>
</list>
```

Hibernate Reference Documentation

> [6.2.3. Indexed collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-indexed)
>   All collection mappings, except those with set and bag semantics, need an index column in the
>   collection table. An index column is a column that maps to an array index, or List index, or
>   Map key.

Comment: does such column need to exist?  I don't really care about the order.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the order, you can use a bag

```
<bag name="networks" cascade="all">
     <key column="parent_id"/>
     <one-to-many class="Network"/>
</bag>
```